# Rails around_action includes before, and after callbacks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Does `around_action` in `ApplicationController::Base` include `before_action` and `after_action`? I understand that `around_action` wraps around the specified action, but would like to know if it also wraps around the before, and after callbacks associated with that action.

For instance, let's look at a code modified from Rails documentation:

```
class ChangesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :some_callback, only: show
  around_action :wrap_in_transaction, only: :show

  ...

  private

  def wrap_in_transaction
    yield unless true
  end
end
```

Will `some_callback` ever be executed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `some_callback` will be executed. These methods are completely unaware of one another, and will be performed in the order they are written.

It may interest you to see the code that rails uses to do this. You can find it at https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/cdaab2c479c819b04cc72a97c52b804832365cef/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb#L180. You will notice that they both call the `_insert_callbacks` method (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/cdaab2c479c819b04cc72a97c52b804832365cef/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb#L87).

Also, why not just try it using console output or something? This type of thing should be very easy to verify with a quick trial (which is, I suspect, the reason behind this question's downvote).

Comment: Thank you. I didn't have much time to test this out, and thought it'd be good to make this knowledge available here on SO.

Comment: @MikeC you're welcome. It was interesting to me, because I didn't know for sure how it worked, either, and had to look it up to satisfy my curiosity.